# Redirect https://www to https://

Tags: redirect, apache2

I use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://kanzan.se%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

to redirect ALL www to non-www, but it doesn't work when I type https://www.kanzan.se. The www is still there!

Comment: Did you enable rewrite trace log so you can see what happens and what rules are hit?

Comment: When enable logging I get "Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server config"

Comment: RewriteLog no longer exists in newer versions. Use "LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3".

Comment: Can you enable rewrite mod?

Comment: Where do I see the logs?

Comment: rewrite mod is enabled

Answer (score 1):

**To redirect `https://www to non www` use the following:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your_domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your_domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

**To redirect www to non-www (while using SSL)**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your_domain.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your_domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

after this don't forget to enable the rewrite mode.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite;
sudo service apache2 restart;
```

Comment: I'm confused.. What do you mean by "while usng ssl"?

Comment: If you have installed SSL certificate then you have to set 443 port

Comment: I used the last one, but same problem

Comment: what is the exact url or your web site ? i will give you exact code.

Comment: https://www.kanzan.se

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. I used this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kanzan.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^ https://kanzan.se%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

in my virtual host for 443. Before I did put all in the global config. I don't understand why it made any difference..